# Запятая после "ну"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "И на каждом (ну, почти) водоеме есть оборудованный пляж". Я поставил после "ну" запятую, но засомневался. Как-то интонационно "ну" и "почти" не разделяются. Может быть, она тут все-таки не нужна?
Подскажите, пожалуйста. И какой правило тут действует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном вами примере запятая после "ну" не нужна. Запятая ставится, если "ну" - междометие (выражает побуждение, удивление). В этом случае междометие "ну" интонационно отделяется от последующего слова и обособляется.
Если "ну" - частица, служащая для усиления последующего высказывания, запятая не ставится. В этом случае оно имеет значение: "так", "итак" (употребляется при подведении итогов); то же, что "допустим", "положим". Интонационно (и знаками препинания) не отделяется от последующих слов.
Зачастую сложно различить частицу "ну" и междометие "ну" по значению. В этих случаях следует ориентироваться на интонацию.